# Jumbotron and Footer are not stretching out to the width of the Mobile Phones Screen Device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Clicking inspect on Google Chrome. When I scroll down the page on the "Toggle Device Toolbar" option. My Jumbotron and Footer are not stretching out to the phones full screen width. I have the code pushed onto CodePen.io for you to look at. The link is provided below. I've also noticed when inspecting the body tag in the html, it gives me exactly where the cut off is occurring.

```
CodePen.io 
https://codepen.io/alexbritoofficial/pen/MWYpbRg
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because class `row` has `margin-left:-15px` & `margin-right:-15px` which is just under the class `w-100` which has `width:100! important`; I made changes to 2 instances below:

- **Instance1**: You can remove `row` because you are not using the `col-**` classes
- **Instance2**: Since you do have `col-**` classes under it, you add a `container-fluid` around it so that `row` doesn't go out of the screen view

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fccd4d;
}

.myNavbar {
  background-color: black;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("/Project/img/Unknown.png");
  height: 400px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: inherit;
}


/* Navigaton Bar List Items CSS */

.menuItems {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.listItem {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.listItemText {
  font-family: "Calistoga", cursive;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18.2px;
}

.listItemText:hover {
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Calistoga", cursive;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #bd3f055b;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.hrSeperator {
  border-color: black;
}

.divSpacer1 {
  height: 10px;
}

.appetizersH1 {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.main-container {
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/* Menu Choice Item Styling */

.menuChoiceItem {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.footerContainer {
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: inherit;
  display: flex;
}

.coastCafeFooterH1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: "Girassol", cursive;
  color: white;
}

.coastCafeFooterParagraph {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: "Girassol", cursive;
  color: white;
}

.plate-identifier {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: black;
}

blockquote .menu-item-h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.appetizer-description {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calistoga&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gelasio|Girassol&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/menuCSS.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge" />
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
<!-- Navigation Bar -->

<div class="w-100">
  <div class=""> <!-- instance1 -->
    <nav class="navbar myNavbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-collapse w-100 fixed-top">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target" style="
        background-color: yellow;">
          <span
            class="navbar-toggler-icon"
          ></span>
        </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/CoastCafeLogoNavIcon.png" /></a>
      <span class="navbar-text listItemText"> </span>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="collapse_target">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-link font-weight-bold listItemText" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold listItemText" href="#"
                >Our Story</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item listItemText">
              <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold listItemText">Our Menu</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="appetizers.html" class="menuItems">Appetizers</a>
              <a href="combinationPlates.html" class="menuItems">Combination Plates</a
                  >
                  <a href="coastSpecialties.html" class="menuItems"
                    >Coast Specialties</a
                  >
                  <a href="chickenBoxes.html" class="menuItems"
                    >Chicken Boxes</a
                  >
                  <a href="classicSandwiches.html" class="menuItems"
                    >Classic Sandwiches</a
                  >
                  <a href="signatureSides.html" class="menuItems"
                    >Signature Sides</a
                  >
                  <a href="homemadeDesserts.html" class="menuItems"
                    >Homemade Desserts</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold listItemText" href="#"
                  >Catering</a
                >
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#" class="menuItems">Request an Event</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold listItemText" href="#">Order Online</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold listItemText" href="#"
                >Contact Us</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="pr-5 mr-5"></div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- End of NavBar -->
    <!-- Coast Cafe Logo -->
    <div class="container-fluid"><!-- instance2 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 d-flex"></div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <img
          src="img/CoastCafeLogoUpdated.png"
          class="img-fluid text-center pt-5 mt-5 mx-auto"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 d-flex text-right"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of the Combination Plates Menu Title  -->

    <div class="container mt-5 pt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1
            class="appetizersH1 display-1 text-sm-center text-md-center text-lg-center text-xl-center "
          >
            Appetizers
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="ml-5 mr-5 hrSeperator" />
      <!-- First Row Menu Items -->
      <div class="row mt-5 pt-5">
        <div class="col">
          <blockquote>
            <h1
              class="menu-item-h1 blockquote text-sm-left text-md-left text-lg-left text-xl-left"
            >
              Corn Bread
            </h1>
          </blockquote>
          <p class="appetizer-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis,
            consequuntur.
          </p>
          <p class="appetizer-description">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <blockquote>
            <h1
              class="menu-item-h1 blockquote text-sm-left text-md-left txt-lg-left text-xl-left"
            >
              Beef Patty
            </h1>
          </blockquote>
          <p class="appetizer-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis,
            consequuntur.
          </p>
          <p class="appetizer-description">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <blockquote class="blockquote">
            <h1
              class="menu-item-h1 blockquote text-sm-left text-md-left text-lg-left text-xl-left"
            >
              Beef & Cheese Patty
            </h1>
          </blockquote>
          <p class="appetizer-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis,
            consequuntur.
          </p>
          <p class="appetizer-description">$4.00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Second Row of Menu Items -->
      <div class="row mt-5 pt-5 d-flex">
        <div class="col">
          <blockquote>
            <h1
              class="menu-item-h1 blockquote text-sm-left text-md-left text-lg-left text-xl-left"
              style="white-space: nowrap;"
            >
              Chicken & Cheese Patty
            </h1>
          </blockquote>
          <p class="appetizer-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis,
            consequuntur.
          </p>
          <p class="appetizer-description">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <blockquote>
            <h1
              class="menu-item-h1 blockquote text-sm-left text-md-left txt-lg-left text-xl-left"
              style="white-space: nowrap;"
            >
              Jerk Chicken & Cheese Patty
            </h1>
          </blockquote>
          <p class="appetizer-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis,
            consequuntur.
          </p>
          <p class="appetizer-description">$4.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <blockquote>
            <h1
              class="menu-item-h1 blockquote text-sm-left text-md-left text-lg-left text-xl-left
              "
              style="white-space: nowrap;"
            >
              Buffalo Chicken & Cheese Patty
            </h1>
          </blockquote>
          <p class="appetizer-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis,
            consequuntur.
          </p>
          <p class="appetizer-description">$4.00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Third Row of Menu Items -->
      <div class="row mt-5 pt-5">
        <div class="col">
          <blockquote>
            <h1 class="menu-item-h1 blockquote text-center">
              Fries
            </h1>
          </blockquote>
          <p class="d-flex justify-content-center appetizer-description">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis,
            consequuntur.
          </p>
          <p class="d-flex justify-content-center appetizer-description">
            (Sm) $4.00
          </p>
          <p class="d-flex justify-content-center appetizer-description">
            (XL) $4.00
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Main Content Body -->

    
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid display-4 mt-5 pt-5"></div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="footerContainer justify-content-center">
      <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 pt-3">
          <h1 class="coastCafeFooterH1 d-flex justify-content-center">
          
          </h1>
          <p class="coastCafeFooterH1 d-flex justify-content-center">
 
          </p>
          <div class="coastCafeFooterH1 d-flex justify-content-center">
         
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex pt-3">
            <a href="">
              <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" style="color: white;"></i>
            </a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/thecoastcafe">
          <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-2x pl-5" style="color: white;"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x pl-5" style="color: white;"></i>
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- JS & JQUERY -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
```